# Limiting requests per user in Google Places

Tags: google-places-api, google-places, quota

I would like to limit the requests a user can make (Google Places) per day to control costs. I know there is a way to limit the total requests made per day... but I would like to set the limit per individual user. Maybe this is a basic question... but is that possible somehow?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far (like e. g. counting visits of a user with cookies or in `window.localStorage`)?

Comment: @digijay I have not... do you think it would work? I'm sorry I don't have a lot of experience with this. How would I proceed after counting visits of a user? Do you think that's the best option?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any context on your project, but I think it would be your best bet. Whenever a user makes a request to the googlemaps API (or whatever you got there) you increment a localStorage property, and then you'd check for any further request if the user quota is reached. Without any code or at least some context this question is off-topic for stackoverflow, so maybe you could add some and show what you've tried already :-)